# How i include /master/header.php in /about/index.php?

Tags: php, html, header, include, directory

How i include /master/header.php in /about/index.php?

localhost:8888/about/index.php:

```
<?php
include '/master/header.php';
?>
```

Comment: That should work, note that with the leading slash you are supplying a full file path, meaning the file must be stored at that location on the system. You probably want a relative path (relative to the current directory) `master/header.php`, `../master/header.php` for "look one folder up" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    include '../master/header.php';
?>
```

Two dots mean back to main folder

Or:

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/master/header.php');
```